# Apache mod_proxy to change /location into port

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, reverse-proxy

I want to achieve a simple thing - proxy `mydomain.com/plex/*` into `localhost:32400/*`. I already have a different proxying rule in place that works fine, but this I cannot get to work.

My `sites-enabled` config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Location "/myapp"> ### This works fine, reverse-proxies to a Tomcat server
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/myapp
        ProxyPassReverse http://example.com/myapp
    </Location>

    <Location "/plex"> ### This does not work
        ProxyPass http://localhost:32400
        ProxyPassReverse http://example.com/plex
    </Location>

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Expected:** If I open URL `http://example.com/plex/web/index.html`, it should be proxied on the server into `http://localhost:32400/web/index.html` - and that page should be fetched. (opening that `localhost` address from the server works fine.

**What I get:** unfortunately all I get is 404 Not Found.

I have found some guides on setting up reverse proxy for Plex (which is what I am trying to do), but they dealt with `https`, subdomains and others. All I want is a very simple redirection between a location and a port.

Thanks for any help

Comment: A few comments. You don't need the <Proxy *> block that is (almost) always for forward proxies only. I would strongly recommend against using ProxyPass inside <Location> blocks, as opposed to the 2 argument form of ProxyPass. I would also strongly recommend using trailing slashes on the arguments to ProxyPass unless you have a very good reason not to. You will find it much easier if you can get plex to deploy as localhost:32400/plex and proxy it the same way you do myapp. As it stands 2nd proxypassreverse should probably be: ProxyPassReverse http://example.com (with the scheme in front)